# Como usar um enumerador como ItemSource de um ComboBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, enums

Supondo que eu tenha o seguinte:

`enum Dias {Segunda, Terça, Quarta, Quinta, Sexta, Sábado, Domingo};`

Como posso usar o enumerador `Dias` como `ItemSource` de um `ComboBox` numa aplicação WPF? Por exemplo:

`<ComboBox Name="ComboDias" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Dias}"/>`

Desta forma, não funciona como o esperado. Gostaria que os itens fossem "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado" e "Domingo".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acrescente duas configurações dentro `Window`

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:StyleAlias="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

sendo que `WpfApplication1` o nome da sua **app**. Logo após crie tags:  `<Window.Resources>` e dentro `ObjectDataProvider`, configurando a chave `<x:Type TypeName="StyleAlias:Dias"/>` onde `Dias` seria o seu `Enum`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="223.031" Width="304.475"          
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:StyleAlias="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
        <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataFromEnum" MethodName="GetValues"
                            ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="StyleAlias:Dias"/>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboDias" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataFromEnum}}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  Margin="10,25,0,0" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Width="268"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

No `ComboBox` no `ItemsSource` ***configure***: `{Binding Source={StaticResource dataFromEnum}}` onde `dataFromEnum` é o nome do `ObjectDataProvider`

**Resposta**: [***SOEn***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6145957/6797930)

---

A maneira mais fácil seria:

```
private void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboDias.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Dias)).Cast<Dias>();
}
```